# How can I add author's name and date in a table on the title page of scrbook class of LaTeX document?

Tags: tables, koma-script, titles, scrbook

I am trying to create a custom title page in an scrbook class of document. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\title{Sample LaTeX Book With Custome Title Page}
\author{Eva}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
            \hline
            Name & : & \textbf{\author} \\
            \hline
            Submission Date & : & \textbf{\date} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the third column, where my name, and the date should appear, remains blank.  I tried to keep @author instead of \author in the third column. But when I did it, the third column had the word "author" instead of taking my name. What am I missing in this?

Comment: `\author` and `\date` are commands with arguments *to set the author and date not to print it*. You could use the internal macros `\@author` and `\@date` (→ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do ), that store the author and date, set by `\author` and `\date`. However, why not just typing the author and date directly at the tabular?

Comment: @cabohah I tried to use the macros \@author and \@date in the table. But that shows the words "author" and "date" respectively in those place, instead of showing my name or submission date. That's why I am getting confused.

Comment: Have you read the page, I've linked in my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the *internal* storage macros, used by `\author{…}` and `\date{…}` (and also by `\maketitle`). Because they have *internal names* using `@`, you either [have to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) or `\csname …\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\title{Sample LaTeX Book With Custome Title Page}
\author{Eva}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
            \hline
            Name & : & \textbf{\csname @author\endcsname} \\
            \hline
            Submission Date & : & \textbf{\csname @date\endcsname} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But I do not see any sense to not make it simple (and avoid internal macros):

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
            \hline
            Name & : & \textbf{Eva} \\
            \hline
            Submission Date & : & \textbf{\today} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Both examples result in:

[image: ugly result]

which is IMHO very ugly, so that I would rather use something like:

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{titlepage}
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{l<{:}l}
          Name & \textbf{Eva} \\
          Submission Date & \textbf{\today} \\
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{titlepage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: better]

or even without the `\fbox`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the perfect answer. Yes, it could be made simpler, if I were working only for me. The issue is that I am creating this format for my other colleagues too, who would use it eventually.

Comment: @Eva the colleagues should be able to also replace a placeholder like `AUTHOR` or `DATE`, if you make a template. If you instead make a package, you could redefine `\maketitle` (or use a titlepage defined using package `uni-titlepage`). In this case, using internal macros wouldn't be a problem. However always note: Distributing a template or a package should also include providing support for it. Responsibility is always a factor. Often I see student templates with very ugly and fragile code that do more harm than benefit.

Comment: I agree with you. The intention is to make a package ultimately. I am myself relatively a newcomer in LaTeX from closed source software like Microsoft Word. So, it is taking some time for me to understand all this. But I will surely look at the resources you have referred to.